# Why am I getting revision.tmp and .revision.time permission errors when running "make install" for Ruby 2.6.5?

Tags: ruby, makefile

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.6.5 on RHEL 7.4, but I'm coming up with permission errors surrounding revision.tmp when running `sudo make install`. I'm not very familiar with Make, so I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is occurring.

```
$ sudo make install
        BASERUBY = /bin/ruby --disable=gems
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable -std=gnu99
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -fexcess-precision=standard -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
        DLDFLAGS = -fstack-protector-strong -pie
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
        LANG = en_US.UTF-8
        LC_ALL =
        LC_CTYPE =
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

/bin/sh: revision.tmp: Permission denied
make: [.revision.time] Error 1 (ignored)
./revision.h unchanged
./tool/ifchange: line 89: .revision.time: Permission denied
make: *** [.revision.time] Error 1
```

Comment: how was this resolved ?

Comment: @Codeformer Instead of using `sudo make install` I dropped into a shell as root (ie. `sudo -i`) to run `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` as root and it installed successfully.